# Hiding phone form number

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a input tag by text type and a lot of divs by numbers similar to phone number, I want to each numbers that type in input, same number remove from div numbers.How can I do it?  I

Comment: Can you please use an example of what you would like your output to be?

Comment: Could you setup a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to visualize your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear on what you want so I'm assuming it's something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/sruw6o2k/

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    var $button = $(this);
    $('#myinput').val($('#myinput').val() + $button.text());
    $button.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:contains()`

```js
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
  $("div:contains("+$(":text").val()+")").hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>0123456789</div>
<div>0123456789</div>
<div>7123456789</div>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" value="0123456789" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your guide, my meaning is not this, but your guide help me